# Store a list of objects in db4o clears after restart

Tags: c#, arraylist, db4o

I have this issue where I have a property of a class which is an ArrayList, and then storeing this class in a db4o container clears the list after a restart of the server.

Class that has the ArrayList property looks somewhat like this:

```
public class Planet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    // Planet has an ArrayList property called Moons.
    public ArrayList Moons { get; set; }
}
```

Populating and storeing the class to the DB

```
if (planet.Moons == null)
{
    planet.Moons = new ArrayList();
    planet.Moons.Add(new Moon("MoonOne"));
    planet.Moons.Add(new Moon("MoonTwo"));

    Database.Store(planet);
}
```

As long as the server is running everything works fine, the list is correct and the values inside it are correct. The other propertys of the class are also correct and fine.

Restarting the server and the list clears. Though the rest of the class is still correct, and everything else in the database is fine, only the list gets cleared for some reason.

Does anyone have any clue to why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you aware of the update depth in db4o? http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/basics/update_concept/update_depth_in_action.htm

Comment: Increasing the UpdateDepth solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Database.Store(planet);

Is this a store or an update? I mean, "planet" object has been retrieved from db prior to setting "Moons" member or is it a newly instantiated obj?

Have you tried it with a simple embedded app ?